# Is there a way to print error message when a user presses the "enter" key instead of throwing an exception or a primitive type error(char to str)?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, char, switch-statement

I am currently working on a project in my first Java class. I am writing a program for a mock company that allows for various user inputs depending on user need for animal registration. The info packet we're provided with has our "Menu Options" pre-coded as 1-6 and 'q' for quit. This makes things difficult since my switch case statement then had to be **char** instead of something more pliable. When I try to input a validation statement that prints an error message for if a user presses 'enter' insead of a valid menu option, it tells me it's incompatible with primative type char. I've tried various ways of converting the char to string, string to char etc, and nothing is working.

Below is the code for my main method without validation that functions fairly well, except for if the user enters incorrect options:

```
    // initialize dog and monkey lists
    public static void main(String[] args){
            initializeDogList();
            initializeMonkeyList();
            char input;
            String userInput;
            
            
            // get user input selection
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            // switch case implemented to run through menu options
            do {
                displayMenu();
                
                // convert to char for user input
                input = scnr.nextLine().charAt(0);
                
                switch(input) {
                    case '1':
                        intakeNewDog(scnr);
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        intakeNewMonkey(scnr);
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        reserveAnimal(scnr);
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        printAnimals('4');
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        printAnimals('5');
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        printAnimals('6');
                        break;
                    case 'q':
                        System.out.println("Rescue Animal System is now closed");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
                        
                }
            }       
            while(input != 'q');
```

When I add the code below to account for when a user presses the 'enter' key, it will print my error message, but won't do anything else. I tried placing it in multiple spots, but placing it below 'displaymenu()' was the only way that got it to run at all, but not correctly. Is there a different way to approach this issue that my class just hasn't taught us yet?

```
                //check input for empty entry
                userInput = scnr.nextLine();
                while (userInput.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    input = '?';
                    System.out.println("Please make a valid selection");
                    return; 
                }
```

Comment: `return` will return from the main method (exit). Replace `return;` by `continue;`. https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option would be to change your input processing to check for an empty string before doing `.char(0)`

```
displayMenu();
            
// convert to char for user input
userInput = scnr.nextLine();
if (userInput.isEmpty()) {
    input = '?'; // initialize input
    System.out.println("Please make a valid selection");
    continue; // bad input, start loop again...
}
input = userInput.charAt(0);
// process input character
```